# Cómo saber hasta qué versión se puede usar un permiso en Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, react-native, jetpack-compose

He estado leyendo varios posts en la página de Android para ver hasta qué versión se puede usar el permiso de Android para la biometría:

La página dice que esta versión está deprecada desde la versión de la API 28 de Android, pero actualmente la app que tenemos desarrollada está en API 29 y sigue funcionando... El problema es que queremos actualizar a API 30 y he estado leyendo información al respecto pero no dice en qué versión específicamente dejará de funcionar. Obviamente en un futuro tendremos que actualizar este permiso hacia el que están sugiriendo ahora, pero la idea es poder seguir usando este permiso hasta que deje de funcionar (ya que se deberían hacer cambios en varias apps).

¿Alguno de ustedes sabrá dónde puedo encontrar esa información?

Dejo el link de referencia del permiso en Android:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission?hl=es-419#USE_FINGERPRINT

Espero puedan ayudarme,
muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Si revisas la documentación oficial indica se agrego en API 23 y es obsoleta a partir de la API 28:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como comentas

> El problema es que queremos actualizar a API 30 y he estado leyendo
> información al respecto pero no dice en qué versión específicamente
> dejará de funcionar.

Si te indican que es obsoleto el permiso desde API 28, lo ideal es que dejes de usarlo.

> Obviamente en un futuro tendremos que actualizar este permiso hacia el
> que están sugiriendo ahora, pero la idea es poder seguir usando este
> permiso hasta que deje de funcionar (ya que se deberían hacer cambios
> en varias apps).

En algún momento tienes que actualizar y deberías realizarlo ya, te puedo confirmar que en API 30 aún existe la constante definida pero marcada como obsoleta:

```
@Deprecated
public static final String USE_FINGERPRINT = "android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT";
```

**Aunque en los boletines oficiales de Google en ocasiones indica sobre métodos o clases que serán eliminadas en alguna versión de API, no hay un lugar oficial donde se indique cuando específicamente se eliminará algo del SDK.**